# bash compare files between folders, and if they don't exit, do something

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with regular pictures, and another with resized ones.

The goal is to check if a picture is not resized, do the resizing and save in another folder.

I'm using an `echo` for simplicity, because I don't have the comparison working.

```sh
for file in ../regular/*.jpg;
do   
    img=`basename "$file"`

    FILE=./resized/$img

    if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$img NOT RESIZED"
    fi  
done
```

This code just echoes `NOT RESIZED` for all the pictures in the regular folder i.e. it doesn't seem to make the comparison at all.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: In which directory do you run your script?

Comment: Did you try to debug your script by echoing `FILE` after the assignment?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Shit, you are right @Cyrus, I put the wrong folder.

Comment: I assumed that, because your script works for me without problems.

Comment: I would not conserve this simple operating error here.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ../regular/*.jpg;
FILE=./resized/$img
```

1. Try to use absolute path, You can also add echo $FILE to see what scripts tries to verify
2. If this directory contains a huge amount of files, you can exceed command line length limit (usually ~4kb-32kb)
3. You are using quotas in basename command, why? If your images could contain spaces, you should use quotas also in "if" command, check script below

```sh
for file in ../regular/*.jpg;
do   
    img=$(basename "$file")
    if [ ! -f "./resized/$img" ]; then
        echo "$img NOT RESIZED"
    fi  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `diff` command to compare directories:

```
diff -r "$PATH1" "$PATH2"
```